# JavaScript promise issues with q.timeout

Tags: promise

I’m using `q.timeout` see below

```
        _.each(AppRegistry.apps, function (app, i) {
            if (app.isaProjectFormat()) {
                console.dir(app.typeName);

                Q.timeout(
                    this.generateThemes(app),
                    90 * 1000, // 90 seconds
                    'brand-async-generation-timeout'
```

I wrap the above around an `_.each`. Unfortunately, the then function is always getting called before the generateThemes function is done for each item in the array. I’m I using the promises correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
promise.timeout(10000).then(
  function (result) {
    // will be called if the promise resolves normally
    console.log(result);
  },
  function (err) {
    // will be called if the promise is rejected, or the 10 second timeout occurs
    console.log(err);
  }
);
```

https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisetimeoutms-message